# Set up diskspace quotas according to a dynamic backend on Linux

Tags: linux, dynamic, disk-space-utilization

I am currently setting up a machine which involves a lot of user accounts coming from a dynamic backend (MySQL database). I have successfully setup the system so that it uses that backend for all account-related operations (authentication, session, password management, ...) but now I would like to set quotas for all these users.

Now, when it comes to quotas on Linux, I would normally use quota files:

1. Activate quotas on the given filesystem.
2. Create the `aquota.user` file at the FS' root, and remount.
3. Use `quotacheck`, `quotaon`, `quotaoff` and `edquota` to configure everything.

Now, the problem here is that these quota files are static, while many of my UNIX users are stored dynamically in my database. This means that when a user is added through this backend, I need quotas (also stored in the database) to be enforced on him immediately. Since new users may be added at any given moment, I don't really feel like connecting to the server every single time to edit quota information for the new user myself...

Is there a way to store quota information in a dynamic backend, just like other kind of account-related information? Or is there a more "common/typical" way to achieve such results, which I haven't though of?

**(A little background)** These users stored in a MySQL database have their own home directory, and can access it through FTP. Whatever they store there becomes available through a web server (shared hosting), and while PHP scripts may be used, these run with their owner's identity (suPHP). The point is, PureFTPd's quota file (`.ftpquota`) also belongs to the connecting user: while it's still impossible to remove that file through FTP, it may however be done through a PHP script running with similar privileges. I'm therefore looking for a more "robust" way to enforce quotas, that is, not through the FTP server which may be tricked into granting more diskspace than was originally granted.

The machine here is a Linux Debian Wheezy running PureFTPd as the FTP server, and Apache as the web server. Accounts are stored in a MySQL database, and linked to the system through `libnss-mysql` (account information retrieval) and `pam-mysql` (account management). Everything within a user's home belongs to that user and may therefore be altered by that very user.